# Don't have Heap shot analysis

Tags: ios, memory, instruments, heapshot

I am trying to find out where my app has abandoned memory and all the resources I see say to mark a `heap shot`.

However I *only have a mark generation button*. Where should I find the heap shot **button**? Or did it just change.

Sorry I am new to iOS.

Comment: there is no need apologize for being new at anything. This is a good question even two years later. Without questions this site would not work.

Answer (score 23, accepted):

The Mark Generation button is the heapshot button. In Xcode 5 and Xcode 6 the Heapshot Analysis section of the Allocations instrument has been renamed Generations.